# Securely passing info through HTTP Post

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on

If you are on HTTPS then is it secure enough to pass authentication related information(username and password)in plain text from App A to App B using HTTP post?

Comment: That depends on your data & threat model.  For example, maybe App B shouldn't have access to the password at all.

Comment: App B need these details to authenticate users. I don't have any control over App B(don't own source code or can't modify).